# Bundle Expect library with shell script

Tags: expect

I want to create a shell script that uses the Expect library however Expect is not installed on any of the systems where I want to run the script. Can I build Expect from source and then put in same directory as the script? How would you go about this?

Comment: also asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50049520/7552

Answer (score 0):

If all machines are the same architecture and operating system, it *should* work (as long as other required stuff is present...).

Best bet would be to require expect installed on each.